# Third party VueJS component can't be found in node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-component

Using `vue-cli` version 3 for a new `vuejs` project (I've been studying a lot of `vuejs`, but this is the first time trying to implement a third-party component).  I'm trying to use a grid component that looks impressive.  The component is [here](https://future-architect.github.io/cheetah-grid/0.7/demos/gettingstarted/download_vue.html).

I've setup my environment, installed the grid and component using `npm` as instructed from their site, configured my own component and imported everything (I thought) properly.  I've even setup an data array property to use as a test to fill my grid.  I ran `npm install` and confirmed the folders were installed in my `node_modules` folder (they are there).  Here is my `main.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import CGrid from 'vue-cheetah-grid'

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(CGrid);

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

And here is my `App.vue` :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <reports-grid></reports-grid>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ReportsGrid from './components/ReportsGrid.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app', 
  components: {
    reportsGrid: ReportsGrid
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is my component file, `ReportsGrid.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div class="grid">
        <c-grid ref="grid" :data="records" :frozen-col-count="1">

            <c-grid-column field="team" width="85">
                Team
            </c-grid-column>
            <c-grid-column-group caption="Estimate">

                <c-grid-column field="quotenum">
                    Quote #
                </c-grid-column>

                <c-grid-column field="quotedate">
                    Date
                </c-grid-column>

                <c-grid-column field="customer">
                    Customer
                </c-grid-column>

                <c-grid-column field="country">
                    Country
                </c-grid-column>

                <c-grid-column field="type">
                    Type
                </c-grid-column>

                <c-grid-column field="quoteamount">
                    Quote Amount
                </c-grid-column>
            </c-grid-column-group>
            <c-grid-column-group caption="Sales Order">

                <c-grid-column field="salesordernum">
                    Sales Order #
                </c-grid-column>

                <c-grid-column field="salesorderamount">
                    Sales Order Amount
                </c-grid-column>

                <c-grid-column field="margin">
                    Average Margin
                </c-grid-column>

                <c-grid-column field="status">
                    Status
                </c-grid-column>
            </c-grid-column-group>
        </c-grid>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'app',
        data: function() {
            return {
                 records: [
                {
                    team: 'GG', quotenum: '20211', quotedate:'today', customer: 'AirNN', country: 'Peru', salesordernum: '11111',
                    type: 'Production', quoteamount: '$1300', salesorderamount: '$1200', margin: '25%', status: 'WIN Partial'
                },
                {
                    team: 'LL', quotenum: '20200', quotedate:'today', customer: 'Paris', country: 'Mexico', salesordernum: '11122',
                    type: 'Bid', quoteamount: '$12300', salesorderamount: '$10300', margin: '20%', status: 'WIN Partial'
                }
            ]

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I run this I don't see anything on my page (no errors either).  I noticed in my `main.js` my linter is throwing an error on the line `import CGrid from 'vue-cheetah-grid'` (this error doesn't show up in my terminal, just in my main.js:

```
[ts]
Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-cheetah-grid'. 'path.to/node_modules/vue-cheetah-grid/dist/vueCheetahGrid.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/vue-cheetah-grid` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vue-cheetah-grid';`
```

This is a new error to me.  The folders are in the `node_modules` folder.  I even tried the `npm install @types/vue-cheetah-grid` but it still didn't work.

Comment: Please, add the code of the `ReportsGrid.vue`.

Comment: Done.  Many thanks

Comment: did you try `add new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vue-cheetah-grid';` ?

Comment: I looked it up but I have no experience with that and wasn't sure.  I was actually still reading on it while waiting on help from here.  Where do I add such a declaration?

Comment: Something occurred to me... do I need to build the original `cheetah-grid` first?  It's installed via npm, but do I have to complile?  https://future-architect.github.io/cheetah-grid/0.7/demos/gettingstarted/download.html

Comment: Also when I try to run `npm install @types/vue-cheetah-grid` I get an error  of `error 404 Not Found: @types/vue-cheetah-grid@latest`

Comment: Shouldn't `records` be an array?

Comment: I was just looking at that when you commented.  I updated it and wrapped it in brackets.  Still not displaying though.  Updated code above

Comment: Ok so technically it is working.  But for some reason the CSS is hiding the grid.  I started unchecking classes and the grid and data appeared.  I have no idea why though.  See this screenshot.  It's hiding elements off the page and I'm not sure why https://imgur.com/a/EXOfMDQ

Comment: I suppose I need to ask dev why this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be with the height style.

Looking at the page source for the Cheetah Vue demo, they have dropped in some styles that seem to override the standard cheetah styles.

If you add this to your component, it looks ok

```js
<style scoped>
  html {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
  }
  .contents {
    padding: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .demo-grid {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 1px #ddd;
  }
  .demo-grid.large {
    height: 500px;
  }
  .demo-grid.middle {
    height: 300px;   
  }
  .demo-grid.small {
    height: 240px;   
  }
  .log {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
  }
  .hljs { 
    tab-size: 4;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Interesting, so they broke their own component?  Thank you!  I guess I'll just style it the way I want using your code as a start.  Many thanks!